# C# Linq query to join two lists and assign the result to new list

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

First model:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Sid { get; set; }
}
```

Second model:

```
public class GuidelinesWorkTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sid { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I have this method:

```
public IEnumerable<GuidelinesWorkTeam> GetWorkTeamsWhereChangeName(
       IEnumerable<Group> adGroups,
       IEnumerable<GuidelinesWorkTeam> gwtItems)
    {
        return gwtItems.Where(gwtItem => adGroups.Any(adGroup => gwtItem.Sid == adGroup.Sid && gwtItem.Name != adGroup.Name));
    }
```

adGroups input

| Object | Name | Sid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [0] | WorkTeam1 | Sid1 |
| [1] | WorkTeam3 | Sid2 |

gwtItems input

| Object | Id | Name | Sid | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [0] | 1 | WorkTeam1 | Sid1 | true |
| [1] | 2 | WorkTeam2 | Sid2 | true |

desired result

| Object | Id | Name | Sid | Active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [0] | 2 | WorkTeam3 | Sid2 | true |

Demo is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u1bbFw)

I need to return an `IEnumerable<GuidelinesWorkTeam>` (Or other IEnumerable, because I need only `adGroup.Name` and `gwtItem.Id`) element if they meet the above criteria, but replacing `gwtItem.Name` with `adGroup.Name`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using `Select`?

Comment: yes but i couldn't solve my problem. maybe I used it wrong

Comment: Can you post what you want the input and output lists to look like? Mostly as a sanity check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, I would like to propose two different approaches to solve it:

- filtering the items in `adGroups` before associating the `adGroups` items with the `gwtItems` items
- (filtering the items in `gwtItems` as you have already done, and then) associating the `gwtItems` items with the `adGroups` items

Depending on which variable (`adGroups` or `gwtItems`) benefits most from being filtered initially, you may choose which approach fits your use case best.

#### Filtering the `adGroups` items, then associating them with the `gwtItems` items

Here, all applicable items from `adGroups` are grouped by `Sid` before each `Sid`-based grouping is associated with items from `gwtItems` based on the gwtItem's `Sid` value. After associating `adGroups` groupings and `gwtItems` with equal `Sid` (and unequal `Name`, due to the initial filtering of `adGroups`) using [`.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0), we select each associated adGroup and gwtItem pair's `adGroup.Name` and `gwtItem.Id` in a [`tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) and use `SelectMany()` to flatten the collection (from a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable< * >>` to a `IEnumerable< * >`).

```csharp
public IEnumerable<( string Name, int Id )> GetWorkTeamsWhereChangeName(
    IEnumerable<Group> adGroups,
    IEnumerable<GuidelinesWorkTeam> gwtItems)
{
    return adGroups
        .Where(adGroup => gwtItems.Any(gwtItem => 
            gwtItem.Sid == adGroup.Sid &&
            gwtItem.Name != adGroup.Name))
        .GroupBy(adGroup => adGroup.Sid)
        .Join(gwtItems,
            grouping => grouping.Key,
            gwtItem => gwtItem.Sid,
            ( grouping, gwtItem ) => grouping
                .Select(adGroup => ( adGroup.Name, gwtItem.Id )))
        .SelectMany(_ => _);
}
```

#### Associating the `gwtItems` items with the `adGroups` items (after filtering the `gwtItems` first)

Here, the items from `gwtItems` are first associated with the items from `adGroups` based on the `Sid` property from the respective classes, using `.Join()` before a tuple containing relevant information is returned from the `.Join()` operation; then, only the associated items that actually have different names are selected and converted to a simpler tuple.

Your original filtering should possibly be included if it is probable that it will filter out many items from `gwtItems`; but it shouldn't be necessary to obtain the desired result.

```csharp
public IEnumerable<( string Name, int Id )> GetWorkTeamsWhereChangeName(
   IEnumerable<Group> adGroups,
   IEnumerable<GuidelinesWorkTeam> gwtItems)
{
    return gwtItems
        // Original filtering
        .Where(gwtItem => adGroups.Any(adGroup => 
            gwtItem.Sid == adGroup.Sid &&
            gwtItem.Name != adGroup.Name))
        // Association and final filtering
        .Join(adGroups,
            gwtItem => gwtItem.Sid,
            adGroup => adGroup.Sid,
            ( gwtItem, adGroup ) => ( 
                ChangedName: gwtItem.Name != adGroup.Name,
                Name: adGroup.Name,
                Id: gwtItem.Id))
        .Where(workTeam => workTeam.ChangedName)
        .Select(workTeam => ( workTeam.Name, workTeam.Id ));
}
```